# LocalStorage doesn't set items into itself

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a bug with LocalStorage on react.js. I try to set a todo into it, but it doesn't load. This is the code:

```js
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import TodoList from './TodoList';
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = 'todoApp.todos'
function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const TodoNameRef = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedTodos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY))
    if (storedTodos) setTodos(storedTodos)
  }, [])
  useEffect(() => {
      localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(todos))
  }, [todos])
  function HandleAddTodo(e){
    const name = TodoNameRef.current.value
    if (name==='') return
    setTodos(prevTodos => {
      return[...prevTodos, { id:uuidv4(), name:name, complete:false}]
    })
    TodoNameRef.current.value = null
  }

  return (
    <>
      <TodoList todos={todos}/>
      <input ref={TodoNameRef} type="text" />
      <button onClick={HandleAddTodo}>Add todo</button>
      <button>clear todo</button>
      <p>0 left todo</p>
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

This is TodoList.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import Todo from './Todo';
export default function TodoList({ todos }) {
  return (
    todos.map(todo =>{
        return <Todo key ={todo.id} todo={todo} />
    })
    
  )
}
```

And as last Todo.js:

```js
import React from 'react'

export default function Todo({ todo }) {
  return (
    <div>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" checked={todo.complete}/>
            {todo.name}
        </label>
        
    </div>
  )
}
```

What the code has to do is load a todo into the local storage, and after refreshing the page  reload it into the document. The code I implemented
I just started with react but I hope anyone can pass me the right code to make it work. If anyone need extra explenation, say it to me.

Kind regards, *anonymous*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need of adding the second `useEffect`.
You can set your `local Storage` while submitting in the `handleTodo` function.
Things you need to add or remove :

1. Remove the Second `useEffect`.
2. Modify your handleTodo function :

   ```
    const nextTodos = [...todos, { id:uuidv4(), name:name,complete:false}];
    setTodos(nextTodos);
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(nextTodos));
   ```

Note: Make sure you won't pass `todos` instead of `nextTodos` as we know `setTodos` is an async function There might be a chance we are setting a previous copy of `todos`

Comment: Thanks, Dival. You've solved my bug! I noticed that items only stored when a new item got assingned to the todo array. So I followed your answer, and then it was alright. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You added the getItem and setItem methods of localStorage in two useEffect hooks.
The following code intializes the todo value in localStorage when reloading the page.

```
  useEffect(() => {
      localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(todos))
  }, [todos])
```

So you need to set the todo value in HandleAddTodo event.

I edited your code and look forward it will help you.

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import TodoList from './TodoList';
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = 'todoApp.todos'
function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const TodoNameRef = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    const storageItem = localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY);
    const storedTodos = storageItem ? JSON.parse(storageItem) : [];
    if (storedTodos) setTodos(storedTodos)
  }, []);

  function HandleAddTodo(e){
    const name = TodoNameRef.current.value;
    if (name==='') return;
    const nextTodos = [...todos, { id:uuidv4(), name:name, complete:false}];
    setTodos(nextTodos);
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(nextTodos));//replace todos to nextTodos
    TodoNameRef.current.value = null
  }

  return (
    <>
      <TodoList todos={todos}/>
      <input ref={TodoNameRef} type="text" />
      <button onClick={HandleAddTodo}>Add todo</button>
      <button>clear todo</button>
      <p>0 left todo</p>
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Even better would be to put the fetching of the local storage into the `useState` callback.

Comment: @Maradox, I copyed your code, and it worked, but for only one todo. If I try to store another todo, it doesn't store. Perhaps this is a hint: I get an error in my console: "unexpected token , in JSON. If anyone can help me, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Did you check what value is set on todos state? I can't detect what the bug is from only above code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to decouple your local storage logic into it's own react hook. That way you can handle getting and setting the state and updating the local storage along the way, and more importantly, reuse it over multiple components.

The example below is way to implement this with a custom hook.

```
const useLocalStorage = (storageKey, defaultValue = null) => {
  const [storage, setStorage] = useState(() => {
    const storedData = localStorage.getItem(storageKey);
    if (storedData === null) {
      return defaultValue;
    }

    try {
      const parsedStoredData = JSON.parse(storedData);
      return parsedStoredData;
    } catch(error) {
      console.error(error);
      return defaultValue;
    }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(storageKey, JSON.stringify(storage));
  }, [storage]);

  return [storage, setStorage];
};

export default useLocalStorage;
```

And you'll use it just like how you would use a `useState` hook. (Under the surface it is not really more than a state with some side effects.)

```
const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = 'todoApp.todos'

function App() {
   const [todos, setTodos] = useLocalStorage(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, []);

   const handleAddTodo = event => {
    setTodos(prevTodos => {
      return[...prevTodos, { 
        id: uuidv4(), 
        name, 
        complete: false
      }]
    })
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={HandleAddTodo}>Add todo</button>
  );
}
```